# Urllib2 <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>

Tags: python, api, csv, urllib2, yahoo

I have a python program that uses several APIs, including two from Yahoo!. One i am having trouble with, however. it always gives me the error `<urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>` Here are the outputs from various terminal commands to try to get the data from "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv":

my code:

```
def stocks():
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message('RasPi Stocks\nUsing Yahoo!')
    time.sleep(2)
    val = 1
    for i in stockslst:
#           host = urllib2.socket.gethostbyname('finance.yahoo.com')
            req = urllib2.Request('http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=' + i + '&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv$
            req.add_header('Host:', 'finance.yahoo.com')
            mdata = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            csvdata = [row for row in csv.reader(mdata)]
            sname = csvdata[0][0]
            last1 = float(csvdata[0][2])
            last2 = float(csvdata[0][3])
            if last1 > last2:
                    r = 0
            if last1 < last2:
                    r = 1
            if last1 == last2:
                    r = 126
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.message(sname + '\n' + chr(r) + str(last1))
            time.sleep(2)
```

my program:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python lcddisplayrpi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lcddisplayrpi.py", line 132, in <module>
stocks()
File "lcddisplayrpi.py", line 113, in stocks
mdata = urllib2.urlopen(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1211, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
```

curl the problematic address:

```
curl "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv"
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirect</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 "<em>http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv</em>".<p></B></FONT>

<!-- default "Redirect" response (301) -->
</BODY>
```

wget the problematic address:

```
 wget "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv"
--2013-10-06 09:01:30--  http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv
Resolving finance.yahoo.com (finance.yahoo.com)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address `finance.yahoo.com'
```

I can get the csv data in a web browser on the same computer. as hinted in the curl command, I tried changing it to download.finance.yahoo.com, but no luck with the python program. I tried curl again:

```
curl "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nsl1l2op&e=.csv"
"Google Inc.","GOOG",872.35,-,876.00,876.09
```

This is the data I want. I don't know what is wrong with my python program.

Comment: In my system I can get the correct data, either with wget or python. Are you behind some kind of proxy?

Comment: @Salem I don't know. I have a DSL modem hooked up to an ethernet switch, which my Raspberry Pi is connected to.